# Widget not getting updated when i insert some values into an widget database

Tags: android, listview, widget

i have created a widget for my app which is going to display the browser history.

when user started to browse, the URL will be recorded in Widget's database. but its not syncing with widget. its not reflecting in widgets list-view.

i have followed the below link to create a widget using list-view.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

i have seen some of the stack overflow Q/A. it saying like, To avoid bad coding the sync will happen on every 30 mins. but if you see whats-app's widget, widget will get updated whenever whats-app receives message.

Can any one please help me to sync the widget whenever the new value is added to it's database or please give me the strong reason why we cant sync the widget but whats-app can.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this documentation. I used this to update my widget according to a change in the database(firebase). There is a method called `onDataSetChanged()` which will be triggered by `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` as per any change in the database.
[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#fresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbESp.png)

Below is a snippet of information copied from above documentation.

> The following figure illustrates the flow that occurs in an app widget
>   that uses collections when updates occur. It shows how the app widget
>   code interacts with the RemoteViewsFactory, and how you can trigger
>   updates:

[image]